# Where statement with conditional subquery

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to use following Statement

```
DECLARE @MatnrFilter TABLE ( ListValue VARCHAR(50) )

INSERT  INTO @MatnrFilter
    ( ListValue )
VALUES  ( '167436' )
INSERT  INTO @MatnrFilter
        ( ListValue )
VALUES  ( '167447' )

SELECT  *
FROM    ios.BaseData_2013
WHERE   Materialnummer IN ( CASE WHEN ( ( SELECT TOP 1
                                                ListValue
                                      FROM      @MatnrFilter
                                    ) IS NULL ) THEN Materialnummer
                             ELSE ( SELECT  *
                                    FROM    @MatnrFilter
                                  )
                        END )
```

I want to filter just when there are values in @MtnrFilter. Here I am getting the error message

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

Is there another way to do that?

Tanks 
Andi

Comment: take a look here: ELSE ( SELECT  *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE Materialnummer IN (SELECT ListValue FROM @MatnrFilter)
OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @MatnrFilter)
```

Would seem to cover it. A `CASE` expression has to return a single scalar value (per row).

Answer (score 0):

Change the WHERE statement to the following:

```
WHERE   NOT EXISTS(SELECT ListValue FROM @MatnrFilter)
        OR Materialnummer IN ( SELECT  ListValue FROM    @MatnrFilter)
```